# How to change text color programmatically in kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I found similar questions on stakeOverFlow, but the answers did not help me

file: values.xml

```
<color name= "orange_or">#EC7000</color>
```

my textView in kotlin

```
private val myText: TextView bi bindView(R.id.my_text)

if (conditionTrue) {
    //my text color = orange_or
}
```

how would I change this textView to that color from the values.xml file in the kotlin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
   //with a color  
   myText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.orange_or))
   //with a selector
   myText.setTextColor(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.xxx))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but could I get the variable from values.xml?

Comment: @ramossuit what do you mean with the variable? You can get the value using `R.color.orange_or`

Comment: in the project values ​​file there are all the colors and values ​​of the project that we used in the xml